# How to display styled print out of XML on website

Tags: html, css, xml

I am using some XML and I want to display it on site, But will prefer to display some styled version. Let's say in some boostrap table or something like that but somehow i have no clue how.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
  <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
  <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
  <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
  <item>
    <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/rss</link>
    <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>XML Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml</link>
    <description>New XML tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
</channel>

</rss>
```

So let's say I have this XML, and i want to style it to table where will be:

```
     Title          |            Link              |              Desc
W3Schools Home Page | http://www.w3schools.com/rss | New RSS tutorial on W3Schools
XML Tutorial        | http://www.w3schools.com/xml | New XML tutorial on W3Schools
```

Can you give me some inditions or some can someone write example code for me to make it more clear.

I hope I don't ask for too much. Thank you all !!

Comment: Except for the first row (with “Title”, “Link”, “Desc”), this could rather easily be handled with a simple CSS style sheet (without involving HTML in any way). But do you really just want to display the data in tabular format?

Comment: Nope, i want to display it in table or something like that... or as some news... some bootstrap thing prolly, tabulators was jsut example

Comment: Then you should describe the context in the question itself. The question would probably still be too broad; there are many possible approaches.

Comment: Is there a way without XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally this done with an XSLT which is an instruction sheet for the browser to converts the xml into html automagically.

Checkout out:

https://greenbytes.de/tech/tc/xslt/

...for some great links to book and additional information.

There are some working examples at:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_examples.asp

Comment: Thank you @ZacWolf, yea it have looks smart. Is there a chance you can write a  short example based on that XML above?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_apply